# Join us in Denver for our opening reception!

Tags: discussion, announcements

In case you haven't seen my [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/join-us-for-our-opening-reception-of-stack-exchange-denver/) announcing this, we’re planning a big office shindig for the evening of September 27th at our new Denver office, and you're all invited!

Check out the details [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/embeddedform?awesm=s.tk_denver&formkey=dG9LX0pQSTN1b1dlR2plVHJvcnRteWc6MQ), and RSVP today.

We hope to see you there!

Comment: Why can't you guys ever do anything interesting in Seattle instead?  Breakin' my heart here... \*sniff\*

Comment: I don't have the time... :-(

Comment: Oh, will the Shog be there? Will he be walking around with various objects covering his face [like Wilson](http://i.cdn.turner.com/v5cache/TBS/Images/Dynamic/i10/homeimprov_wilson_240x260_053020041834.jpg)?

Comment: @animuson Shog will be around, shogging up the joint as only he can.

Comment: It's 1:59PM, amanaP. And yes, I'll be there @animuson

Comment: @Shog9 will you be catering the event with dishes featuring [fried potatoes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146168/what-was-the-interruption-chat)?

Comment: Depends a lot on whether or not I have a house by then, @Pop. (The Denver office's caterer does some fine mashed 'taters though)

Comment: I finally get to meet some Stackers! ... ... Exchangers? Overflowers? Ok, ok, fine, I get to meet some Stack Exchange employees in person! Hooray!

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: I'd go if only I didn't live 2000 miles away. I'd say this event is "too localized" ;)

Comment: +1 I hope there are such events in Philippines, Singapore or in Asia! That will definitely rock :)

Comment: Nice! I'll be there! Say "hi" to the guy with a white shirt and green backpack.

Comment: It'd be fun... if you weren't 8 hours away.

Comment: So who's going to be there? Just me and Shog? Hmmm and of course it's Downtown at rush hour :)

Comment: Had a blast.  Met Joel, totally chill guy, met a volunteer mod, and met a whole bunch of interesting people.  I wanted a hoodie, but I can live with a shirt.  A good time was indeed had by myself and my friends.